# Sandcastle MAML math commands

Tags: xml, math, sandcastle

I'm using Sandcastle to document my project. In a conceptual content layout I'm trying to explain some functions, and I'd like to be able to add formulae to describe them. I'm aware of the `math` tag, but so far I'm not exactly sure what is does, the documentation provided with Sandcastle isn't much use as their example is simply italicizing `1+1=2`. I don't need anything super complicated, just fractions, absolute value signs, maybe ordinary derivatives, so if the `math` tag can't do that somehow I would be surprised. Ideally though there if there's a way to use LaTex commands that would be perfect.

Another question: How do you get math commands to centered? I tried `<math placement="center">` like in images, but that didn't work.

Comment: Did you try it out with more depth?